# Javascript Adding Element to DOM Syntax Troubles

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I searched and could not really find an answer for this. I am creating a Javascript function that will easily add an element to the specified element. Here is the syntax:

```
function add(element, to, idName, className) {
    //creates new element for DOM
    var newElement = document.createElement(element);
    //sets ID attribute for element
    var attrId = newElement.createAttribute('id');
    attrId.value = idName;
    //sets class attribute
    var attrClass = newElement.createAttribute('class');
    attrClass.value = className;
    document.getElementById(to).appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Long story short, it doesn't work. Yes, my JS is linked fine to my HTML and I have already used many other functions in the same JS file, but this is the one I am having trouble on. I am sure there is some form of a syntax error but can't seem to find it.

P.S. This is my first time using JS to dynamically add a page element without changing innerHTML directly.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's developer console for errors? If there were a syntax error, you'd see it reported there.

Comment: Please Provide a Fiddle ..

Comment: It says newElement.createAttribute is not a function

Comment: Oh I found the error! I have document.createAttribute instead of newElement.createAttribute

Comment: Actually that did not fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `id` and `class` are already defined in each element.
To access an element's `id`, just do `element.id = id`. As for the classes, there's a thing called `element.classList`, and if you want to add a class just type `element.classList.add("class_name")`, and to remove it type `element.classList.remove("class_name")`.

The correct code now comes as:

```
function add(element, to, idName, className) {
    //creates new element for DOM
    var newElement = document.createElement(element);
    //sets ID attribute for element
    newElement.id = idName;
    //sets class attribute
    newElement.classList.add(className);
    document.getElementById(to).appendChild(newElement);
}
```

check [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) to understand more about classLists

Comment: Thanks! Fixed just about everything except the console gives me an error relating to newElement.classList.add() it says "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified" and points to that line.

Comment: Nevermind, that related to my parameter. Thanks! Solved all my problems! You deserve a cookie.

Comment: @turkey3 the way you give people cookies here is to click the upvote and/or accept buttons.

Comment: @turkey3 in case you simply didn't know how to do what Pointy has said, see that on the left, at the beginning of the answer, there is a number with 2 arrows going in opposite directions. To upvote you click the arrow above the number, and to mark it as correct there should be a button somewhere over there. Click those to tag my answer as correct (which it is)

Comment: Sorry but I do not have a 15 reputation to upvote, but I DID select it as the correct answer.

Comment: thank you! The upvote is not required, it's just a if you think that the user deserves one.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use `.createAttribute()` here. You're creating those attributes, but doing nothing to associate them with the element you're creating. Things are much simpler than that:

```
function add(element, to, idName, className) {
    //creates new element for DOM
    var newElement = document.createElement(element);
    //sets ID attribute for element
    newElement.id = id;
    //sets class attribute
    newElement.className = className;
    document.getElementById(to).appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Note that you're probably going to want to work on the fact that you sometimes need more than just a tag name, id, and class.  `<input>` elements are a good example — they require a "type" attribute (well, not really *require*, but an API like this would need to account for that.)